# How to remedy water running under shingle and fixing damage to rafter?

Tags: roof, water-damage, stucco

We just had some heavy rains and we've seen some paint bubbling on an interior wall and a little bit on the exterior. I examined the outside of the house and think I found the culprit.

Here are some pictures to help describe the issues.[image: wide shot of roof line and rafter]
Wide shot of roof line and rafter

[image: close up of roof and water intrusion under shingle]
Close up of roof and water intrusion under shingle (damage rafter is just below this area).

[image: rafter damage]
Rafter damage

So, I think water is running down our roof and under the shinges (you can see a close up in the second picture). The water is causing the shingles to separate along the roof line. It's also potentially causing the rafter to have water damage.

I scraped away a lot of the peeling paint (probably b/c water is seeping under the paint).  When I scraped away the paint, I saw that there was a lot of caulk and or bondo or something. You can also see that the rafter is cracking, and there's a 1" strip that is loose and I can probably rip out.

I want to fix both of these things.

1st - I need to fix the roof area where water is running under the shingle.
Should I just caulk around the shingle area?  My neighbor has offered some left over APOC roof cement.  I could potentially just glob it on.

2nd - I want to fix the area along the roof line where the shingle is separating from it. I have some caulk...will that work? I watched a video where certain caulks also have a glue like ability, so I think this might work

3rd - I want to fix that damaged rafter.  Should I use bondo, or wood filler?  I want to make sure that it lasts.  It also interfaces with the stucco...so afterwards do I finish with some stucco around the transition from the wall to the rafter?

**UPDATE**
Including a zoomed out view of the roof...as requested by a comment.
[image: roof zoomed out]

---

**UPDATE - After Caukling**
I climbed up onto my roof and did a bunch of caulking, including the issue I posted here.  I just covered that entire area with caulk.

[image: after caulking]

Comment: Can you add a zoomed out picture of the roof from above? Your flashing looks wrong, and any goop-based fix is going to be temporary until you get the flashing right.

Comment: Hi @KMJ.  Just added the photo.  Also, my neighbor pointed out that the shingles don't have enough overhang at the edge of the roof. :(

Comment: The picture confirmed what I thought. Caulk is going to be an OK workaround, but you need to start budgeting for this roof to be replaced. It has multiple problems.

Comment: @KMJ - it's an old roof. Just curious what other problems do you see? Thanks.

Comment: From here it looks like inconsistent overlap, it doesn't go all the way to the edge of the flashing, the flashing install is weird, and there's no guidance for the water at the end of this valley. But maybe I'm just being paranoid or not familiar with normal approaches to installation where you live.

Comment: Looks to me like the valley flashing (at least the left side) should have been continued down over the drip edge of the lower roof.  Also, aren't starter strips supposed to be used along flashing, underneath the shingles?

Comment: Is that a normal valley flashing product?  I just haven't seen one with a ridge like that down the middle.  In any case, I agree that it doesn't appear to be terminated properly at the bottom.